# Generate citation info missing for R packages

Tags: r, roxygen2

The citation (bibtex entry) for any `R` package can be obtained by `citation( "pkg_name" )`.

Also `R` package repository webpage on CRAN usually has an entry called "Citation" which provides a link for the corresponding bibtex entry.

For [roxygen2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html) package, I am unable to find the citation information. Is there a way in R to generate a citation info, if it is missing, in this case roxygen2 do not have a citation info?

I also tried this method, but it did not work.

```
library(devtools)
citation('roxygen2')
# Error in citation("roxygen2") : package ‘roxygen2’ not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to load the package first?

```
require(roxygen2)
citation('roxygen2')

To cite package ‘roxygen2’ in publications use:

  Hadley Wickham, Peter Danenberg and Manuel Eugster (2017). roxygen2: In-Line Documentation for R. R package
  version 6.0.1. https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=roxygen2

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {roxygen2: In-Line Documentation for R},
    author = {Hadley Wickham and Peter Danenberg and Manuel Eugster},
    year = {2017},
    note = {R package version 6.0.1},
    url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=roxygen2},
  }
```

Comment: do I have to install roxygen2 separately? I thought it is installed with devtools package. I may be wrong.

Comment: @Sathish looking at the `devtools` page it's not imported by default, so you'll have to load it separately.

Comment: @Sathish if you start a fresh R session, run `require(devtools)` then `sessionInfo()` you can see all the attached packages, and `roxygen2` isn't attached or loaded via namespace.

Comment: I agree with you. The problem is that roxygen2 is uninstalled for some reason and I was making assumption that I have roxygen2 is installed already on my system